# Serving Static Files via Express & Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, web-development-server

I have a Node.js server, serving some static assets and an EJS file via Express. I have a WebSocket running with Socket.io, but I don't think it's relevant to the issue.

The Server Code:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const path = require('path');

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));
app.use('/session/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {}); //Renders .ejs page to user
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  next();
});
```

This did work at one point, I restored the code to its original version, and it now doesn't work. This is what is confusing me so much.

The page still serves the EJS, but it doesn't load any of the static assets.

I have tried many variations:

- Removing the `path.join`.
- Not having the initial argument `/assets` or `/session/assets`.
- Serving each static file one by one instead of the whole `public/` file.

I've looked at other questions on Stack Overflow about this, but none of the suggestions works for me.

My files structure in the server:

```
app
  L public
    L js
      L // js assets
    L css
      L // CSS assets

  L views
    L index.ejs

  L server.js
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'app/public')));` as you must specific a full path to static folder

Comment: @TBA Thanks for the comment, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. I can see in the chrome web tools there is only 1 thing in the 'sources' on the whole page. The `index` file.

Comment: How does your index file header looks like (which resources are included in the page)?

Comment: Please show what the URLs look like in the rendered HTML for JS and CSS assets.  We need to be able to understand exactly what URL is being requested of your server.